# Use HorizontalAlignment right from within a Frame

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have a `<Frame/>` in my Main page, and a second page is inserted into the frame using `Frame.Navigate(Page)`. The second page contains a `<Grid/>` with a `<Button/>` inside.

The problems comes when I try to align the Button to right, it moves to the right in the designer, but it just stays in the same position (locked to right side of fullscreen). I've tried every combination on the frame and grid to try and get the button to just stick to the right hand side and move with the window resizing, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that settings Width and Height of the page completely messes up stretch resizing, as they will just stretch to the fixed size. So the solution was removing the Width and Height properties of the window.